# Are paraphrased theorems allowed?

Tags: soft-question, advice, publishing

In writing maths papers, if I want to present a theorem or definition from some other paper, would it be acceptable to cite the author and then present a paraphrased version of the theorem/definition in my paper? Note that the theorem is actually quite lengthy.

For example:

We make use of the theorem 5.4 by Anotherauthorname (Year).

{Begin Paraphrased theorem

.....
.....

End Paraphrased theorem}

Or is this considered some kind of plagiarism?

Comment: As long as you attribute the statement/proof of the theorem to the author, and correctly reference the paper it appears in, everything should be fine.

Comment: if the name of the original author is present, it cannot be plagiarism, since you don't claim the result was found by you.

Comment: If you significantly change the formulation of the theorem, it is nice to state this. For example, we use theorem blabla, of blibli, where they state "blu" but in fact "blublu" is proven.

Comment: Note that if the paraphrased version is a non-trivial change (by which I mean it is non-trivial that the new statement follows from the original) and the new version is due to someone else, that person should also be mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not plagiarism to paraphrase another's theorem, provided you cite the author and source fully.

For example, in addition to your reference to said author in the paper itself (name, year of publication), as you have mirrored in your post, include a *full reference* at the end of your paper, among your listing of other references.

Just be careful to paraphrase in a manner that conveys the spirit and substance of the theorem you're citing.